# Move Email from Deleted Folder

Tags: vba, outlook

Recently had an employee leave the company and decided to move a few thousand emails and events to the trash folder in Outlook. Thankfully, I can still recover them manually but I would prefer not have to do them in small batches..

I've got this code but it errors when I try to move items from the "Deleted Items" folder back to the Inbox.

```
Sub MoveItems()
 Dim myNameSpace As Outlook.NameSpace
 Dim myInbox As Outlook.Folder
 Dim myDestFolder As Outlook.Folder
 Dim myItems As Outlook.Items
 Dim myItem As Object

 Set myNameSpace = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
 Set myInbox = myNameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(Deleted Items)
 Set myItems = myInbox.Items
 Set myDestFolder = myInbox.Folders("olFolderInbox")
 Set myItem = myItems.Find("[SenderName] = 'John Smith'")
 While TypeName(myItem) <> "Nothing"
 myItem.Move myDestFolder
 Set myItem = myItems.FindNext
 Wend
End Sub
```

Thoughts?

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Run-Time error '13':
    Type Mismatch

Which i'm assuming is for the Deleted Items folder

Comment: On which line ?

Comment: Why not just open that mailbox in Outlook and move the messages manually? It is a one-time thing, right?

Comment: I agree with @DmitryStreblechenko, it seems like you could just do a search on the employee's name and just manually highlight and move over the results

Comment: Yes and no. There is a mix of mail and calendar items. The calendar items give an issues because it tries to recreate the event and fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to specify the deleted items folder like so:

```
Set myInbox = myNameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderDeletedItems)
```

You can read more examples for specifying folders [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/outlook-vba/articles/namespace-getdefaultfolder-method-outlook) and a list of other options [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/outlook-vba/articles/oldefaultfolders-enumeration-outlook)